# Get LinkedIn user data

Tags: java, oauth, playframework, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I'm using java and I'm able to get the user access token. However I can not fetch data from linkedin. Here is my code:

```
F.Promise<WS.Response> res2 =WS.url("http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(first-name,last-name,positions,picture-url)")
  .setQueryParameter("Authorization","Bearer "+access_token)
get();
```

But I get Unknown authentication scheme error.
I also tried `setHeader` instead of `setQueryParameter` but same thing!
please help!!

Answer (score 0):

Use https instead of http. Also you are mixing headers with query parameters. Use only one. If you want to use headers you can do so with:

```
setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)
```

if you want to use a query parameter:

```
setQueryParameter("oauth2_access_token", accessToken)
```

[LinkedIn Authentication Docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication)

Answer (score 0):

thanks alot salem, i forgot about https. now it works here is my code:

```
 F.Promise<WS.Response> res2 =WS.url("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(first-name,last-name,positions,picture-url)")
                .setHeader("Authorization","Bearer "+access_token)
                .get();
```